# SVG иконка для пункта меню

Tags: android

Можно ли использовать SVG иконку типа как эту http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/favourites-filled-star-symbol_56786#term=star&page=1&position=29 для пункта меню?

Comment: да.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для версий ниже Lollipop лучше конвертировать svg в png того размера, который вам нужен, например с помощью бесплатного редактора [Inscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/download/)

В API 21 (Начиная с Android 5.0) появился класс [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) который позволяет встраивать SVG.

Comment: Приложение поддерживается устройствами с ОС Android 4.0.3 и выше

Comment: Нашел онлайн конвертер который преобразовал иконку в  Vector Drawable. Только не знаю как оно будет работать на андроид 4. В версиях выше все нормально.

Comment: только проблема. размеры height и width 180. Иконка уменьшилась как нужно, но в пункте меню она отображается в справа вверху. Можно ли центрировать иконку посередине.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [VectorDrawableCompat](http://VectorDrawableCompat) начиная с api7

```
<ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

[svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) позволяет получить `VectorDrawable` из `svg`, также можно импортировать `svg` прямо в студии `File -> New -> Vector Asset`

[materialdesignicons](http://materialdesignicons.com) сайт с кучей иконой, который позволяет получать сразу `VectorDrawable`

Comment: Неправильную ссылку дали под materialdesignicons

Comment: @TITAN спасибо.